# RST conditional directives don't work using standard syntax

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I've defined a conditional tag in my makefile so I can use the ONLY directive to conditionally remove blocks of text.

Makefile entry:

> ...
>   set BUILDDIR=_build
>
> sphinx-build -t internal
>   ...

I have a single LINE of information that I need to make disappear for a specific docs build. Here is the instance:

> ```
> general:
>     workspace: "xxx"
>     <first indented list items>
>
> .. only:: internal
>
>     xt-team-name: "phoenix"    # for use with XT Grok - exclude this line otherwise **
>
>     <following list items - must stay put>
> ```

The 'internal' directive works, BUT it wipes out everything following the single line of text, that I DID NOT want to wipe out for this build. I have no spacebar characters or tab stops after the excluded text line - just a bare newline. I thought the newline would end the conditional operation?

What's the trick to get it to work on just the one piece? Can't move anything - it would disrupt the logic of the preceding and following indented sections of information. Tweaked the example to make it clearer.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying the following? Seems to me like the goal is to have 3 parts that are indented at the same level, the second part being optional, is that right?

Comment: Done. It's part of a longer list of indented items.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are asking for. It would be better if you showed basically the two RST codes that you would like to merge into one. Is this a list, or block quotes, or what is that supposed to be?

Comment: @RichardGrace if the answer solved you problem, you should accept it by clicking the green check sign on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

White space has meaning in reStructuredText.

Indent the content that you want to hide for `internal` under the `only` directive.

Do not indent the content that you want to show.

```
general:
    workspace: "xxx"
    ...

.. only:: internal

    xt-team-name: "phoenix"    # for use with XT Grok - exclude this line otherwise **

<following body of information>
```

## Edit

Upon realizing that you want a list of items, not paragraphs, you can still get this to work with proper indentation.

```
List of Items

*   One
*   Two

    .. only:: internal

        * Two and one-half (hidden)

*   Three
```

### `sphinx-build -b html . _build`

[image: sphinx-build -b html . _build]

### `sphinx-build -b html -t internal . _build`

[image]

Also if you do not want "Two and one-half (hidden)" to be a member of a nested list, but of its parent list, then you can dedent it and its `only` directive.

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately, the line in question is part of a much longer indented list. So that's not a solution here. I'll tweak my example to make that even clearer

Comment: Your example is not any clearer. Do you want to conditionally hide `<following body of information>`? If yes, then indent it. If no, then do not indent it.

Comment: Heh. It doesn't work, if that <following body of information> is ALSO indented. Remember, I'm excluding a single list item in the middle of a larger list. The entire list is indented. And not indenting it isn't an option. The integrity of the following content needs to remain.

Comment: You have paragraphs, not a list of items. You can still do conditionals within a list if you properly indent them. I'll update my answer with another example.

Comment: Steve Piercy thank you!! :) Still having trouble getting this to work. No combination of indents works. In this case, I'm only using a single-indent list because if I can get that to work, the concept should apply to multi-layer lists just by applying another indent across the board.

Am grateful for your help. Haven't had a publication platform give me so much difficulty with simple tasks since the CP/M days. I would also give you a thumbs up but StackOverflow won't allow me to. Can't embed an image either, which might also be helpful <frustrated>.

Comment: @RichardGrace well, I'm merely making guesses about your reStructuredText. All you have in your question is a representation of your rst, not your actual rst. Please provide actual rst so that we can reproduce the issue and possibly solve it. You can replace actual text with lorem ipsum if it is sensitive.

Comment: Thank you! Ehh. I tried exactly your example at exactly those levels of indentation - nothing works the way I need. Still wind up with a new line of white space where the condition occurs because of Sphinx's requirements. The only way to avoid it is to only conditionalize the last list item. This is not a solution. Close, but no cigar. I might have to settle for that, but after using almost every publication tool that exists for many years, this is a real comedown.

Comment: Although it works locally, how to let ReadtheDocs use -t internal command when we publish our project to the GitHub repo? What is the change we need to make in Makefile?